# Using void in functions. Won't recognise

Tags: c++, function, struct, void

I'm having a problem with this function. The function is supposed to return a type of `StoredData`.

This is my struct:

```
struct StoredData
{
    void* data;
    int size;
    int type;
    int compareValue;

    StoredData():

        size(0),
        type(0),
        compareValue(0){}
};
```

And this is my function:

```
StoredData SDI::Array::create(int size, int type, int compareValue)
{
    StoredData temp;
    void* data;
    int input;
    int input2;
    std::cout<<"What type of data would you like to insert?"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"1 - Integer"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"2 - Boolean"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>input;
    std::cout<<"What is the value?"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>input2;
    switch (input)
    {
    case 1:
        size = sizeof(int);
        type = 0;
        data = new int;
        *data = (int)input2;
        break;
    case 2:
        size = sizeof(bool);
        type = 1;
        data = new bool;
        *data = (bool)input2;
        break;
    }
    temp.compareValue=input2;
    temp.data = data;
    temp.type = type;
    temp.size = size;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm having a problem with the line within the case statements with

```
*data = (bool)input2;
```

The error that I'm getting is that it must be a pointer to a complete object type. I need the `void` variable to recognize the data, and I'm getting no luck. Anybody know a workaround?

I'm getting 2 error messages for each. The first is,

```
illegal indirection
```

And the second ones are,

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'void *'

error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'bool' to 'void *'
```

Comment: Why are you using a `void` type instead of (say) a `union` type?  One other problem that sticks out is there is no memory allocated for `data` to reference...

Comment: Dont use neither void* or union. Use Boost::variant.

Comment: @Davidbrcz Is this question tagged boost?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin:  Just because someone doesn't ask about a particular technology doesn't mean that technology isn't the best tool for the job.

Comment: @JohnDibling In that case the comment would have been better worded as a suggestion than an order.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin:  It was obviously just a suggestion written with economy of verbage.  Nobody here thinks they can *order* OP to do anything.

Comment: @ John Dibling. May be he doesn't know boost::variant. That is why comments are made for : suggesting new ideas a little bit aside from the original question.

And void* and union should be avoided at all cost and modern and type-safe solution should be prefered. That is why I STRONGLY advice the usage of boost::variant. Better ?

Comment: @Davidbrcz:  You're preaching to the choir.

Comment: @John Dibling yes I am. 

Because otherwise, one day you have to handle legacy code full of void*,union, and thousand of traps because no one told the guy who wrote that code he could do it in a better, safer way.

Comment: @Davidbrcz:  [Preaching to the choir](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/preach+to+the+choir)

Comment: Or why not just use two different variables?  (If there were a lot more types, `boost::variant`, or something similar, would be the way to go.  But for just `bool` and `int`?  The extra complication probably doesn't buy much.)

Comment: Is the function to return a value?  I didn't see any `return` statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can't dereference a void pointer.  You will have to cast it to a pointer type you can dereference:

```
*(bool *) data = (bool) input2;
```

Comment: Thanks, but then I get the following error for the line 'temp.data = data;', Error 2 error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'data' used

Comment: That's because the input might not be 1 or 2, in which case `data` will never be initialised.  You can fix this by initialising `data` to NULL and adding some appropriate error handling.

Comment: Also, very strange that that's an error and not a warning.  Do you have a switch like `-Werror` set?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to dereference a void pointer and set its value:

```
*data = (bool)input2;
```

This is meaningless to the compiler.  What type will the result of `*data` be?

You need to cast the `void*` to something meaningful first:

```
*(bool*)data = (bool)input2;
```

Alternatively, you could initialize your dynamic variables with the correct values when you create them:

```
data = new int(input2);
...
data = new bool(input2);
```

Which wouldn't require you to cast anything.

Comment: _"it isn't assigned to a memory location"_ ... Yes it is.  Or more accurately, a memory location is assigned to _it_.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: are you saying that `void *data` is like saying `void data[1]` and so there is memory available to be used?

Comment: No, I'm referring to the `data = new...` above the attempted assignment.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin I missed the `data = new ...` lines.  Updated to fix that problem.  I think you were looking at it from the opposite direction.  I was stating (previously) that `*data` wouldn't be anything because it had not been allocated (again, I missed the `new`s on my first pass through the code).

Answer (score 0):

**void** is an incomplete type.You may not create objects of incomplete type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dereference a plain `void*`, as it could point to basically anything. You aither have to make it point to something other (assigning to another pointer):

```
bool* bool_pointer = new bool;
*bool_pointer = static_cast<bool>(input2);
data = bool_pointer;
```

Or use typecasting:

```
*reinterpret_cast<bool*>(data) = static_cast<bool>(input2);
```